# Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: The user that PassengerDefaultUser refers to, '$(APACHE_RUN_USER)', does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: The user that PassengerDefaultUser refers to, '$(APACHE_RUN_USER)', does not exist.
 Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations

I'm getting this error, but the user www-data, used by apache2 is there.

Running on UBUNTU 13.04. Passenger version 4.0.7

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a configuration problem in your Apache. Somewhere in your config files, perhaps your init script, you told Apache to use '$(APACHE_RUN_USER)' (in verbatim) as the username. Obviously the intention is to let bash replace that expression with the actual username, but that didn't happen and the string was used in verbatim.

Comment: I couldn't find any visible error in apache2.conf, so I got an old copy and replaced the file. I had to manually modify it to reflect the current configuration. Solved.

Comment: Probably it was some non-visible character that end up being inserted into the file. I visually compared line-by-line the two files. They are the same.
One result in the error, other works fine.